# Stringify Object Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, api, axios, stringify

I have a problem getting my value to string. I have used this method before, but I don't know how to do it when I am working with an array. I simply don't get the value and it says "undefined" when I try to specify with playerData.summonerName. When I type playerData alone, I get the full array with all the data that I need to use, but I can't specify which data I want. Is there any other smart way of doing this or how do I fix this??

Hope someone can help, sorry for the bad English.

```
axios.get(APICallString).then(function (response) {
    //Success
        setPlayerdata(response.data);
    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log(response);
    })
}
console.log(playerData);
```

[Logging the data works fine.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FPr0G.png)

```
{JSON.stringify(playerData) != '{}' ?
<>
  <p>{playerData.summonerName}</p>

  <div className="inline-flex w-24 h-24">
  </div>
  <p>Summoner Level: {playerData.summonerName}</p>
```

(summonerName) is not working.

[How I usually do it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOVQu.png)

[Here is all the logged data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGS5P.png)

Hopefully you understand my issue.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't run a map function on the array to stringify each index position?

Comment: If `playerData` is an array then maybe you should use `{playerData[0].summonerName}`. Or use `{playerData.map(....)}` as suggested in the previous comment, if there can be multiple entries.

Comment: Besides all that, doing `{JSON.stringify(playerData) != '{}' ?
<> .... </> : .... } ` is a really odd and inefficient way of checking what is inside `playerData`. If you know that it is (or should be) an **array** then use e.g. `{playerData.length > 0 ?
<> .... </> : .... } `. It is a lot more readable and expresses that you have knowledge about the data that you are processing.